# delimeter chararecter for a string consists of multiple regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I need to store multiple regular expressions in just one string and then retrieve and parse it to the original regular expressions. Which delimeter character should i use to separate these regular expressions.

Comment: use `+` to bind them. use `()` to make different groups. Using `.group()` then you can access each of the regex you want.

Comment: It's always better to include the exact example to illustrate your question. Without it it is hard to tell what you are actually trying to achieve. Most possibly you are talking about groups.

Answer (score 1):

It might look like below as a pseudo code:

```
    String Regex="(regexOne)"+"(regexTwo)";
    Pattern pt=Pattern.compile(Regex);
    String line
    Matcher match=pt.matcher(line);
    
    if(match.find()){

       String matchedWithFirstRegex=match.group(1);
       String matchedWithSecondRegex=match.group(2);

     }
```